# c# processes the same serially received byte twice sometimes

Tags: c#, debugging, serial-port, backgroundworker

My application was processing serially received bytes and I've noticed a weird bug. Sometimes a byte (which always happens to be 0x03) gets processed 2x and I don't know why.

When I receive a byte (or several) I add them to a string using `+= ReadExisting()`. This string forms my buffer. A background worker processes all bytes of the string until the string is empty. The first element of the string gets deleted after it is read in, this makes `string.Length()` return a smaller number every while loop cycle.

```
private void serial_DataReceived(object sender, SerialDataReceivedEventArgs e)
        {
            rxBuffer += serial.ReadExisting(); // adds new bytes to buffer

            try { backgroundWorker1.RunWorkerAsync(); } catch { } // starts background worker if it is not working already.
        }


        private void backgroundWorker1_DoWork(object sender, System.ComponentModel.DoWorkEventArgs e)
        {
            while (rxBuffer.Length > 0) 
            {
                byte b = Convert.ToByte(rxBuffer[0]); // reads in the next byte    
                rxBuffer = rxBuffer.Remove(0, 1); // deletes this byte from the string

           // ... code ... does things do the UI and stuff
```

I am sure that some serial bytes run in that while loop 2x. I have seen it in my output. For some reasons the double byte is always 0x03. Note that `rxBuffer` is not touched anywhere else in the program.

```
Bullseye set at (0,2)
2:05:10  << 0x80
2:05:10  << 0x3
2:05:10  << 0x13
Bullseye set at (1,2)
2:05:10  << 0x80
2:05:10  << 0x3
2:05:10  << 0x3 <--- this one should not be there.
Bullseye set at (3,0)
2:05:10  << 0x14
2:05:10  << 0x80
2:05:10  << 0x3
2:05:10  << 0x15
Bullseye set at (3,2)
2:05:10  << 0x80
2:05:10  << 0x3
2:05:10  << 0x16
Bullseye set at (4,2)
```

Why is this happening and how can I fix this? is it related to the asynchronous byte reading and background worker???

Comment: You share a resource on 2 Threads. You need to synchronize. Or even better: Use a Thread-Safe Buffer.

Comment: It could be the read event is occurring when you are doing the remove.  When an event occurs you have to make sure it doesn't interfere with the in-line code.

Comment: If you want to figure out if this is indeed a threading problem, also output current thread id and length of buffer ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For a quick & **dirty** fix:

```
private readonly object _lock = new object();
private void serial_DataReceived(object sender, SerialDataReceivedEventArgs e)
    {
        lock( _lock )
        {
        rxBuffer += serial.ReadExisting(); // adds new bytes to buffer
        }
        try { backgroundWorker1.RunWorkerAsync(); } catch { } // starts background worker if it is not working already.
    }


    private void backgroundWorker1_DoWork(object sender, System.ComponentModel.DoWorkEventArgs e)
    {
        lock( _lock)
        {
        while (rxBuffer.Length > 0) 
        {
            byte b = Convert.ToByte(rxBuffer[0]); // reads in the next byte    
            rxBuffer = rxBuffer.Remove(0, 1); // deletes this byte from the string

       // ... code ... does things do the UI and stuff
       } // end while
       } // end lock
```

More sophisticated solutions would need more info about your class and more changes made to your code.

Comment: Tnx it seems to work. My solution was to Invoke the while loop function and ditch the background worker. I don't know what would be 'less worse'